# How to use prompt code repeatedly in Perl script

Tags: perl

```
sub prompt {
  my ($query) = @_; # take a prompt string as argument
  local $| = 1; # activate autoflush to immediately show the prompt
  print $query;
  chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
  return $answer;
}


sub prompt_yn {
  my ($query) = @_;
  my $answer = prompt("$query (Y/N): ");
  return lc($answer) eq 'y';
}


if (prompt_yn("Do you want to start a process")){
    my $list1 = prompt("Enter ID:\n");
    my $list2 = prompt("Enter Name:\n");

    print $list1;
    print $list2;
  ## $list1 and $list2 will be used in the code here..
  #...
  #.....
}
```

I want to repeat the contents of the `if` block again and again, prompting again each time it completes if I press y from `(Y/N)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
if (prompt_yn("Do you want to start a process")){
```

with

```
while (prompt_yn("Do you want to start a process")){
```

?